# Mongoid 3.0 embedded 1-N query for listing all embedded fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Suppose an [Embedded 1-N](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_many) model like the following :

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :group_name 

  embeds_many :albums
end

class Album
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  field :sold

  embedded_in :band
end
```

How can I get a full list of Album names for each Band ?

I mean I have to get all bands at firsts, then for each band I'll get his name and I tried some variations of the following :

```
Band.all.each do |band|
  band.albums.all.each do |album|
    album.name
  end
end
```

but doesn't work, what am I missing ?

UPDATE

following [abhas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051778/abhas), it just works adding array :

```
album_array = []
Band.all.each do |band|
  band.albums.all.each do |album|
    album_array << album.name
  end
end
```

then

```
album_array.each{|a|a}
```

to get the list back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the loop you have gave is correct it works just fine, but you are not saving any value of `album.name` anywhere. Just save it in array or something and check the contents of the array. I think it will have all the names.